# What do I need for autocomplete and ctrl+click to work in eclipse after importing a project from Perforce and converting it to a maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, perforce

Currently I have perforce that I am importing my project into eclipse from. After I import my project into eclipse I right click on the project go to configure and convert to maven project. After doing all of this I do NOT have autocomplete for the code working and I do NOT have ctrl+click working.

#### System Specs:

- OS: Windows 7 x64
- RAM: 8gb
- CPU: Intel core i5
- HDD: 128gb SDD
- Eclipse Version: Juno 4.2 JavaEE
- Maven m2e Version: 1.1.0
- Perforce Version: 2012.2.486944

#### Attempts at a Fix

1. I have noticed that when I right click on my project and look to go to Java Build Path it does not exist.
2. Under my right click menu properties and under builders I only have "Maven Project Builder"
3. I have tried to add the proper `<buildCommand>` for the java builder and the proper `<natures>` in the `.project` file. This does NOT fix my issue but does add the Java Build Path I couldn't see in 1. (below is my unaltered .project file)
4. I have navigated to the `.metadata>.plugins` and deleted the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` to eclipse rebuild its indices.

#### Error Received when trying ctrl+click autocomplete or a right click>References>Workspace

*The resource is not on the build path of a Java project*

#### `.project` file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <projectDescription>
        <name>project</name>
        <comment></comment>
        <projects>
        </projects>
        <buildSpec>
            <buildCommand>
                <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
                    <arguments>
                    </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
        </buildSpec>
        <natures>
            <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        </natures>
    </projectDescription>
```

Is there something simple that I have overlooked, or a step that I forgot to do? Any help regarding this issue would be great.

(**I have searched though issues relating to the ctrl+click and the autocomplete but none of the solutions that I have found have helped and none seem to match the eclipse+perforce+maven issue, but sorry in advance if this topic was covered in a different post*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright here is what I did and found out.

I started over with a new copy of eclipse 4.2 EE and redownloaded all of the plugins that I needed: m2e and perforce

#### If you have a flat Maven Project

1. Import the project from perforce, right click on the project>configure>Convert to Maven Project
2. Converting the flat project to a Maven Project indexed everything allowing for the ctrl+click/ctrl+space functionality

#### If you have a multi module Maven Project

1. Check out the project using the perforce plugin into your workspace
2. Import said project as an Existing Maven Project
3. Eclipse/Maven will automatically find all of the poms underneath the parent directory and build/index your workspace
4. After that same as above the ctrl+click/ctrl+space functionality should work

My oversight was that the project I was having issues with I did not realize was a multi module maven project and importing it from perforce and trying to convert the parent folder to a maven project did not cause maven to look at all of the poms in the parent's sub-directories. Hope this helps anyone else having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The way I use Perforce+Maven+Eclipse is to first import my projects as Maven first, and then later right-click the project > `Team` > `Share Project` by linking it against my perforce repository.  I find that Eclipse doesn't properly manage projects with Maven if I don't directly import it as a Maven project from the start.

Comment: This project is already under Perforce control, it is not a new project that I am committing to Perforce. So in that case would I still import as a Maven Project?

Comment: I used P4V to download my project to `My Documents` folder.  Then, I used Eclipse to import "An existing Maven project".  After the project is imported and in Eclipse, I then right-click the project and choose Team > Share Project.  Share doesn't make a new project in your Perforce repository, it just links against it so it knows where to make changes and checkouts from.

Comment: I have tried importing as a Maven project and I still have the same issue. I forgot to add the error I get when I try to do a ctrl+space for auto complete (check above for the error)

Comment: Have you tried adding the source directories manually in your Java Build Path?

Comment: See above, I don't have a Java build path unless I explicitly add the java builder/nature to my .project file, and even then when I add my folder into the build path I do not get the desired behavior.